# Can you calculate $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$ geometrically?

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, proof-without-words

I am learning Integrals from [What is the sum $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$? - Week $11$ - Lecture $2$ - Mooculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRSip64OS-o)
and I still don't get how to **calculate $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$ geometrically**:

According to the video, $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$ can be seen as a triangle like this:
[the triangle of $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9zv.png)

So I can make a copy of the triangle and combine them like this to get a rectangular:
[the rectangular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14oUx.png), hence the area is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

But I realize that I don't have to assemble the rectangular, because **the area of the triangle** is easy to computer, which is $\frac{k\cdot k}{2}$.

So which one is the right one, which is one is the real geometric view of $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$, $\frac{k^2}{2}$ or $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$?

Comment: More like stairs than triangle really.

Comment: The "square" drawing and the rectangle drawing are the same picture, just flipped. In both cases you have a $10 \times 11$ rectangle, or $k \times k+1$ rectangle

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And as DanielV points out, you can't apply the formula for the area of a triangle because the shape isn't a triangle, it's more of a staircase. So you're underestimating the area since the triangle fits inside the staircase

Comment: Although the staricase method can be adapted to get the correct answer. The extra parts of the shape after you remove the inner triangle are also smaller triangles. You have $k$ of these small excess triangles (one for each column/row), and all of them have base and height $1$. So by adding this to the total you get that the final area is $$\underbrace{\frac{k\cdot k}{2} }_{\text{Triangle}}+\underbrace{\left( \frac12 +\frac12+\dots+\frac12\right)}_{k \text{ small triangles}}=\frac{k\cdot (k+1)}{2}$$

Comment: From your diagram with the dots, you really get $k$ by $k+1$  dots.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvpIy.png

Comment: Someone should take all these comments and make an answer.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Proofs_without_words

Answer (score 2):

Actually, think of it not as a triangle, but as a trapezium (or a trapezoid if you are in the US).

The shape has a top length of $1$, not $0$, hence it is not a triangle.

You probably understand it but I will give you an example anyways:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{5}n$$
⬤
⬤⬤
⬤⬤⬤
⬤⬤⬤⬤
⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤

Let's double the dots to form a rectangle:

⬤◯◯◯◯◯
⬤⬤◯◯◯◯
⬤⬤⬤◯◯◯
⬤⬤⬤⬤◯◯
⬤⬤⬤⬤⬤◯

Number of black and white dots $=$ Length $\times$ Width

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{5}n=5\times(5+1)$$

The number of black dots is just half of it (We doubled it first)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{5}n=\frac{5\times(5+1)}{2}$$

To generalise it:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}n=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks bro, I'm in China by the way

Comment: 不用谢啦；我在西澳    :)     Math Stack Exchange 很好用的

Comment: 哈哈谢啦，第一次用，发现了:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for pointing out **the whole picture is not a triangle**, I focused too much on the picture made of dots, neglecting the fact that **the number $1$ is a 'square', but not a dot**, so combining them will actually get a stair.

I drew a new picture of $1+2+3+\ldots+k$.

[image: the old picture and the new picture]

When $k$ is large enough, the stair can be seen as a trapezoid

And the result of $1+2+3+4+\ldots+k$ can be seen as:

1. the area of the trapezoid: $(k+1)k/2$
2. half of the rectangular: $(k+1)k/2$

Wait! Is this how we get the formula for the area of a trapezoid??